# Geting an error of 220 in laravel for mail function

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

In my laravel project i configured a mail file and env as below. and getting an error **Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 220 but got code "502", with message "502 Command not implemented
"**

mail.php file

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587), 
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'alfiza@adaptit.co.uk',
        'name' => 'oData',
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],

];
```

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:FB3usUpI/uPm6VLzx2yR0xHcE61ZxHU6MC6QCBk6wHE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

OCONNECT_URL=http://localhost:8001/
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=odata_demo2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Do I required to add any extentions in my ini? In my another desktop system it's working very well.But when I get in my laptop it showing an error of 220 in sending email.I also found this same question here (in stackover flo not working for me.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share code you have write to send the email ?

Comment: $email_data['data'] = $data;
Mail::send('mail.exception', $email_data, function($message){
                                $message->to(['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'])
                                        ->subject('oConnect Job send Exception');
                            });

Comment: I am sending my dynamic data in $email_data to exception file and send this mail to 2 email ids.

Comment: I have run into cases where I could not mail through a third party from my local system and received that same error. When pushing it to a staging or production environment it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an encryption `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` which is not enabled on your localhost.

Use`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null` in the env file for localhost, or enable it (tls) for your localhost if gmail requires it.